# Units In The Last Place - Intuition

Tags: floating-point, precision

I am reading David Goldberg's "What Every Computer Scientist Must Know About Floating Point Numbers" and came across the section on ULPs. He gives an example:

Actual result : **0.0314 = 3.14 x 10 <sup>-2</sup>**

Closest FP no: **3.12 x 10 <sup>-2</sup>**

So, ULP = **(3.14 - 3.12) x 10 <sup>2</sup> = 2**

However, I am not able to develop an intuition of what this actually means and need some help. What does 'units' mean here?

Comment: I have Goldberg’s paper, both a copy of the original 1991 publication and an edited reprint for which I do not have a date. I do not find the example you show in either version. (There is an example using .0314, but it says the **error** is 2 units in the last place, not that **ULP** is 2.) Please give your complete source for the information: Where you found it, the date and any other identifying information, and the section name or number in which you see the example.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html, section "Relative Error and ULPs"

Comment: The title of the paper is *What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*, not *What Every Computer Scientist Must Know About Floating Point Numbers*, and the text in the paper is different than what is given in this question. It is important not to alter words when conveying them to other people, especially in ways that change their meaning. Goldberg is discussing the result of a computation, not the “Closest FP no.” Those are different things. And Goldberg says the error is 2 ULP, not that ULP = 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question appears to refer to this passage in *What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*:

> Consider the floating-point format with β = 10 and *p* = 3, which will be used throughout this section. If the result of a floating-point computation is 3.12 × 10<sup>-2</sup>, and the answer when computed to infinite precision is .0314, it is clear that this is in error by 2 units in the last place.

There are differences between this passage and that given in the question:

- Goldberg describes 3.12 × 10<sup>-2</sup> as the **result** of a computation, not as the “Closest FP no.” A computation may be a sequence of operations, and, although each operation individually may produce the floating-point number closest to the result of the corresponding real-number (“infinite precision”) operation given the same operands, the final result of the sequence is not necessarily the floating-point number closest to the result that would be obtained if all operations had been performed with real-number operations instead of floating-point operations.
- Goldberg says the floating-point result has an error of 2 ULP relative to the real-number result, not that “ULP = 2.”

Given β = 10 and *p* = 3, the format uses significands of three decimal digits. The ULP, Unit of Least Precision, is simply the position value of the least significant digit. So, for the number .0312, the ULP is .0001. This passage in Goldberg observes that the difference between .0314 and .0312 is 2 ULP.

Comment: Thanks, it answers that. It's embarrassing that I wrote the name of the paper incorrectly, should have been more careful. One follow up question. The author says, "If the result of a calculation is the floating-point number nearest to the correct result, it still might be in error by as much as .5 ulp." Why can't it be more than that? Ex - Infinite precision: 3.148, result: 3.14 (in some hypothetical FP system), then this gives me an error of .8 ULPs?

Comment: @PrashantPandey: Neighboring floating-point values are 1 ULP apart, by definition of ULP. Any number between them is closer to one of them than the other or is exactly at the midpoint. So it is never more than ½ ULP away from the nearest representable value. If the mathematical result were 3.148 in a format where 3.14 and 3.15 were representable, we would use 3.15 as the result, since it is closer.

Comment: "Neighboring floating-point values are 1 ULP apart, by definition of ULP" has a discontinuity with `power_of_2` its predecessor `nextafter(power_of_2, 0)`  The ULP of those two values differ so the distance between as in "1 ULP" seems to refer to "1 ULP(smaller(x,next_x))`.  Of course you are aware, yet "Neighboring floating-point values are 1 ULP apart" has its edge cases deserving recognition.